# Микроконтроллеры и Java

Tags: java, jvm, микроконтроллеры

Интересует такой вопрос. Допустим, у меня есть какая-то кнопка, которая лежит на столе. Какие микроконтроллеры, устройства и т.п. можно использовать, чтобы реализовать взаимодействие этой кнопки и `java`?

Comment: вы хотите запускать java на микроконтроллере?

Comment: ну я слышал, что есть такая плата arduino, на которой работает jvm

Comment: есть такая, но зачем? определитесь, что именно вы хотите.

Comment: мне нужно, например, считывать нажатие кнопки, время и координаты на глобальной карте

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Я не понел что автор хочет:) Ардуина, есть такое, но какой jvm? есть транслятор джавы в си ардуины насколько я помню и апи для работы, но не сама джава на ардуине. На ардуине процветает си.

Comment: А так, любое устройство, общение происходит по протаколу serial. На джаве уже реализован апи для работы с com портами(кросплатформенно), вы сможете отправлять или получать данные, но я вижу опыта у вас нет, как и самой платы..

Comment: а как api называется

Comment: Вот статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/133766/ с помощью этого апи, можно хоть с usb модемами общятся:)

Comment: Из моего опыта arduino и jSSC. Также к этой статье надобы добавить http://www.quizful.net/post/java-serial-ports (там описывается как получить все открытые порты).

Comment: Из самых простых вариантов - разобрать дешевую мышку или клавиатуру, и подцепить к ней кнопку.

Comment: Да, и + самый универсальный(про клаву и пайку джойстиков), а про мышь мне не ведомо.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Поскольку Java изначально разрабатывалась [для программирования холодильников и кофеварок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5), было бы странно, если бы возможность работы с железом была утрачена напрочь.

Самый простой вариант подключения кнопки к микроконтроллеру - это порты GPIO, которые широко распространены в embedded мире. Кнопка одним контактом подключается к выводу порта, другим - к земле (GND). Дальше микроконтроллер либо сам что-то делает, либо по UART/USB/Ethernet/WiFi/Bluetooth отправляет сообщение о нажатой кнопке куда-то еще.

Непосредственно по железу варианты есть следующие.

1. Использовать специализированный микроконтроллер, заточенный под Java.

   Да, такие есть. Например семейство 3G-модулей Centerion. Прошивка представляет собой мидлет Java ME и может заливаться в том числе по воздуху. Прослушивание порта выглядит как-то так:

   ```
   Vector inPins = new Vector();
   inPins.addElement("GPIO11");

   InPort inPort = new InPort(inPins);  
   inPort.addListener(new InPortListener() {
       public void portValueChanged(int val) {
           System.out.println("Port value: " + val);
       }
   });
   ```

---

2. Использовать полноценную встраиваемую систему общего назначения на базе ARM-процессора, такую как BeagleBone или RaspberryPi.

   Там у вас будет полноценный Linux с возможностью установки полноценной Java SE или Java SE Embedded. А порты будут доступны через файловую систему как устройства вроде `/sys/class/gpio/gpio49`. Можно взаимодействовать с портом обычными средствами файлового ввода-вывода (что будет относительно медленно, хотя и достаточно для многих задач) или через прямой досутп к памяти через memory-mapped файл `/dev/mem` (что будет быстро).

   Но куда приятнее будет воспользоваться развесистым API сторонней библиотеки [pi4j](http://pi4j.com/):

   ```
   GpioController gpioController = GpioFactory.getInstance();
   GpioPinDigitalInput pin02 = gpioController.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02,PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);
   pin02.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
       @Override
       public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent gpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent) {
           System.out.println("state: " + gpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent.getState());
       }
   });
   ```

   Кроме того, существует еще и Java ME Embedded, предоставляющий нативный API доступа к портам в пакете `com.oracle.deviceaccess`:

   ```
   GPIOPin switchPin = null;
   switchPin = (GPIOPin) PeripheralManager.open(1);
   switchPin.setInputListener(new PinListener() {
       @Override
       public void valueChanged(PinEvent event) {
          // do something
       }
   });
   ```

   К слову, жизнь тут не ограничена ARM, есть и MIPS и Intel Atom. Но подходы там те же.

   Очень интересными выглядят сторонние программные платформы на основе Java:

   - [MicroEJ](http://www.microej.com/products/device-software-development/microej-os/). На Youtube есть ролик, где java-приложение с графикой исполняется на очень слабом железе (*Cortex™-M0+ @48 MHz, 256 KB Flash, 32 KB RAM*).
   - [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/index.html) от Google, ранее известная как Brillo.

---

3. Удивительно, но на Java можно писать под 8-битные AVR-микроконтроллеры (те самые, на которых построена Arduino)!

   Это стало возможным благодаря [HaikuVM](http://haiku-vm.sourceforge.net/), которая транслирует байткод Java из .class-файлов в С-структуры, линкует к ним интерпретатор и формирует на выходе обычный для AVR-микроконтроллеров HEX-файл, который шьется в железку как обычно.

   Еще есть:

   - [NanoVM](http://www.harbaum.org/till/nanovm/index.shtml) - виртуальная машина подмножества Java, занимающая 8 кБ в флэш-памяти.
   - [uJ](http://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=05.Projects&proj=12.%20uJ%20-%20a%20micro%20JVM) - эта VM крупнее (десятки килобайт), но обещает полную поддержку байткода, многопоточность и `synchronized`.

   Если вы хотите нопку подключить к Arduino, а его в свою очередь подключить к компьютеру и делать что-то на компьютере по нажатию на кнопку, попробуйте [JArduino](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/JArduino/wiki). Этот API требует залить на Arduino свою прошивку, после чего вы сможете взаимодействовать с устройством из обычной Java-программы на своем компьютере.