# Автозапуск java программы на raspberry-pi

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, intel, прошивка

Всем привет. Скажите пожалуйста как сделать такое устройство (за основу взято  raspberry либо gallileo) или прошить, чтобы при включении питания, включалась моя java программа, сделанная под linux и жила своей жизнью без внешнего воздействия юзера?

P.S. Сразу говорю, что программа должна будет работать с внешними датчиками, такими как : датчик света, температуры и микрофоном.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что запихивать жабу внутрь малинки - неблагодарное занятие. Как и работать с датчиками (реалтайм же ж?) из жабы

Comment: На Raspberry же linux: вы можете поставить jre и спокойно запускать.

Comment: Вообще, посмотрите тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608977/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-java

Comment: @rjhdby Java внутри малинки дело уже довольно обыденное. Отдельно существует тенденция сборки хобби кластеров на пачке малинок.

Comment: Nofate, ну это тогда понятно как запускать и взаимодействовать с железом, а вот как поставить на автозапуск мою программу?

Comment: А есть возможность заюзать cron?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy
вариант 1(не использовать для вечных циклов):
Идем в папку /usr/sbin/ там создаем новый файл(название на ваше усмотрение), в нем пишем строку #!/bin/sh под ней пишем то что вы хотите выполнить java -jar или что там у вас. 
Даем добро  - sudo chmod ugo+x <имя_файла>

открываем rc.local
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
перед exit 0 пишем путь к своему файлу /usr/sbin/<имя файла>

вариант2: научится создавать демонов)
https://habrahabr.ru/post/141003/

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok а вот пылесосы, кофемашинки и прочую бытовуху на  "linux", так же делают?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, если ваш вопрос только про то, как автоматически запускать на linux программу, то укажите в вопросе, какой конкретной дистрибутив вы запускаете на малинке.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Вариант который я вам дал достаточно деревянный, можно также похимичить с bashrc но подойдет для решения мелких задач, если хотите построить что то хорошее - учите баш и пишите демоны, с правильным запуском и остановкой  и т.д.
Вот еще вариант с cron http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545049/autorun-jar-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-after-boot-up-rc-local-not-working

Здесь в ссылках куча проектов и полезной инфы по ним
http://electronicdesign.com/embedded/coffee-dessert-java-and-raspberry-pi